# Trying to shift a message to lowercase and it is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

```js
if (message.content.startsWith('s!stats passing')) {
  const args1 = message.content.slice(16).split();
  const command1 = args1.shift().toLowerCase();
  editedmessage = command1
  if(client.passing[editedmessage] == undefined) {
    message.channel.send(editedmessage + ' is not in the passing statabase. If you believe he should be DM Toasty')
  } else {
    const args2 = client.passing[editedmessage].Team;
    const command2 = args2.shift().toLowerCase();
    const team = command2
```

So the first args1.shift().toLowercase() works perfectly, but the second one args2.shift().toLowerCase() does not and gives me a TypeError: args2.shift is not a function. I am completely lost as to why this is failing to work.

Comment: Function names are case sensitive. But then the error is about the shift. Maybe args2 is not an array?

Comment: What's the actual content of `command2`

Comment: `args2` is a `number` or a `string`

Comment: May you update your example to be a [mcve]? So we don’t have to guess things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use shift(), args2 need to be an array, because shift(), removes first element from an ! array !